# knitr: How to set a figure path in knit2html without using setwd()?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I work in a project folder let's say that its absolute path is: `/project`. `getwd()`tells me that I am in this project folder. All my file reading and writing are relative to this project root. `/project` has a subfolder `/project/docs/` In which there is a R Mardown file and an R script:

**`report.Rmd` contains:**

````
```{r }
plot(cars)
```
````

**And `knit_reports.R` contains:**

```
library(knitr)
knit2html("./docs/report.Rmd", "./docs/report.html")
```

---

If I run `knit_reports.R`, a html page is generated but figures are not displayed on the page.

The problem is that figures are stored under `/project/figures`. They are not visible for the html document generation. I'm looking for a way to tell knitr to store pictures under `/project/docs/figures` instead.

Setting knitr options root.dir or base.dir in `report.Rmd` doesn't fix the problem, I tried `opts_knit$set(root.dir = "./docs")` or `opts_knit$set(base.dir = "/project/docs")`.

However, if I change the working directory to `/project/docs`:

```
setwd("./docs/")
knit2html("report.Rmd", "report.html")
```

A `/project/docs/figure` folder is created and figures appear on the html page.

Many persons say it's bad to use setwd() in a script, because it messes up reproducibility. How can I tell knitr to place figures in my project subfolder without using setwd()?

Comment: Just to clarify: `setwd()` is only bad after the computing has started. It is not inherently evil. On the contrary, it is always a _good_ idea to `setwd()` _before_ everything else. After that, you assume everything is relative to the current working directory, which will make your life much easier. Setting the `output` argument of `knit()` or `knit2html()` is almost always a bad idea. Well, I admit it is my headache as the package author. I'd encourage you to just `setwd("./docs/"); knit2html("report.Rmd")`, and you get `report.html`.

Comment: Thank you Yihui for your comment. I found that using `opts_knit$set(base.dir = 'docs')` fixes my problem. At first I tried setting `base.dir` in a chunk option of the Rmd document. This didn't work. But setting `base.dir` option in the R script `knit_reports.R` does work and fixes my issue :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at this [page on chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options#chunk_options). In particular, you have two options

1. Use `fig.path` to set the plot directory relative to your working directory (OR)
2. Use `base.dir` to set an absolute directory in which to save plots.

I think (2) might be a better solution in your context. Do not use `setwd()` in a `knitr` document since it is not good practice for keeping documents reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried these options but they don't work in my case. I gave a minimal reproducible example above.

Answer (score 6):

Ramnath's answer to set base.dir was the good answer. But at first I thought the option should be set in Rmd chunks and this didn't work. The option should be set in the R script. This is a question of scope I guess.

So in my example above **knit_reports.R** should contains:

```
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(base.dir = 'docs') # Change the base dir where to save figures
knit2html("./docs/report.Rmd", "./docs/report.html")
```

Comment: I think moving `opts_knit$set(...)` inside the Rmd document and placing it in the first code chunk should also work. In any case, the comment by @yihui of running `knitr` in the same directory as the Rmd file is a very useful one.

Comment: Setting opts_knit$set(...) inside the Rmd document, in a first code chunk, didn't work for me. Tell me what happens if you manage to try with the 2 files above on your system.

Comment: For some reason the .tex documents do not use the proper directory when I am generating the files. They are all just `figure/image_filename`, instead of `base.dir/figure/image_filename`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, that you may run into problems, if you specify a different output-directory in knit2html, as the figure-folder is saved into the original directory. Then, at least in my experience, the html file will not contain your plots. So: as mentioned elsewhere. Try not to change the output directory